# Oracle: query on key/value pairs stored in one of the columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a (large, multi-column) table similar to this:

```
prop1 | prop2 | prop3 | summary
------+-------+-------+----------------------------
      |       |       | "prop1=X, prop2=Y, prop3=Z"
------+-------+-------+----------------------------
  val |       |       | . . . 
------+-------+-------+----------------------------
      |       |   val | . . .
```

All columns are varchars. `prop1`, `prop2`, etc. columns may or may not have a value. If they don't have a value, I need to use the value from `summary` column for filtering purposes. So, suppose I have this query:

```
select * from T where prop1='val1' and prop2='val2' and prop3='val3'
```

I'd like to add something along the lines: if `prop1` is empty, extract `prop1` from `summary` and use that in `where` clause. Is this possible in Oracle? Also, considering that this is a large table with potentially millions of rows, will execution time be a consideration?

Unfortunately, filtering cannot be done in the code because the query also does pagination and passes the current page to another system, so filtering has to be done in SQL.

Comment: If you have the chance, store the values in a proper way. Performance will always suffer if you try to get your values that way and it makes things complicate.

Comment: @PeterLang unfortunately this is a legacy system and not much can be done to alter the existing data.

Comment: That's often the problem, but there are actually people out there designing these tables and sometimes they can be stopped ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the first SELECT anyway:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE prop1= :val1 AND prop2= :val2 AND prop3= :val3
```

but add a `UNION` to handle cases when any prop is null (concatenating chars with null always returns null)

```
UNION SELECT * FROM T where prop1 || prop2 || prop3 IS NULL
 AND COALESCE( prop1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary,'prop1=([^,]+)') ) = :val1
 AND COALESCE( prop2, REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary,'prop2=([^,]+)') ) = :val2
 AND COALESCE( prop3, REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary,'prop3=(.+)') ) = :val3
```

variant to handle empty strings :

```
UNION SELECT * FROM T where LENGTH(prop1) * LENGTH(prop2) * LENGTH(prop3) = 0
 AND prop1 || REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary,'prop1=([^,]+)') = :val1
 AND prop2 || REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary,'prop2=([^,]+)') = :val2
 AND prop3 || REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary,'prop3=(.+)') = :val3
```

Comment: Awesome, this works. One minor correction - since 'propN' is part of regexp equality has to include it on both sides, so simple `or` will work for my purposes: `select * from T
where prop1 = :val1 or
REGEXP_SUBSTR(summary, 'prop1=([^,]+)') = ('prop1=' || :val1)` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if a case statement would suit your needs? Im not sure I 100% understand your question, and on moble. Maybe something like this:

```
Select * from from T 
where CASE when prop1 not null then prop1 ='val1'
           when prop2 not null then prop2 ='val2'
           when prop3 not null then prop3 ='val3'
      END
```